# google charts showing name on top of chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am working with column chart for showing data.

I would like to show on top of each column the name of column.

My array is loke like this:

```
0: (3) ["Date", "United State", "Australia"] 
1: (3) ["Week 48", 66, 67]
2: (3) ["Week 02", 66, 0]
```

I tried with adding { role: 'annotation' }  in my header but no results.

I would like to have something like this. I don't have idea where can I start, any hint or help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the annotation column should follow each series column that needs an annotation

the array should be structured as follows...

```
["Date", "United States", {role: 'annotation'}, "Australia", {role: 'annotation'}],
["Week 48", 66, "United States", 67, "Australia"],
["Week 02", 66, "United States", 0, "Australia"]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Date", "United States", {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, "Australia", {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],
    ["Week 48", 66, "United States", 67, "Australia"],
    ["Week 02", 66, "United States", 0, "Australia"]
  ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataTable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```